# Tablesorter sortReset

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the most recent version of the tablesorter jQuery plugin and trying to use the sortReset option. I cannot get it to work. The script is working because the disable sorting for columns 2 and 4 works. Any ideas?

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#noteTable").tablesorter({
         // third click on the header will reset column to default - unsorted
         sortReset: true,

         //header options 
         headers: {
             // second column 
             1: {
                 // disable sorting 
                 sorter: false,
             },
             // fourth column
             3: {
                 // disable sorting 
                 sorter: false

             },

         }
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1724/

There is also a `sortResetKey` option which is `"ctrlKey"` by default and allows you to ctrl-click on the header to reset the sort.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  sortResetKey : "ctrlKey"
});
```